# Add a break after a specific word with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a website (built in WordPress) and I have a table plugin where I cannot break words or text by simply using the `br` tag or even insert `span` because the table plugin does not allowes HTML Tags.

What I want to achieve is to break some `th` texts.

In the specific I would like to split this text like this:

Anzahl
Zimmer

Netto-
wohnfläche

Verkaufs-
preis
CHF

I would like to know how can I achieve this with it.

Here the table `th`

```
<th data-class="expand" class="wdtheader sort  column-block sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Haus: activate to sort column ascending">Haus</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-wohnung sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Wohnung: activate to sort column ascending">Wohnung</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-anzahlzimmer sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Anzahl Zimmer: activate to sort column ascending">Anzahl Zimmer</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-etage sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Etage: activate to sort column ascending">Etage</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-nettowohnflache sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Netto-wohnfläche: activate to sort column ascending">Netto-wohnfläche</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-sitzplatz sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Aussenfläche: activate to sort column ascending">Aussenfläche</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-verkaufspreischf sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Verkaufspreis CHF: activate to sort column ascending">Verkaufspreis CHF</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-pdf sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="PDF: activate to sort column ascending">PDF</th>
<th class="wdtheader sort  column-anfrage sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Anfrage: activate to sort column ascending">Anfrage</th>
```

Full table code here https://jsfiddle.net/0bkgLqx5/

Comment: Have you tried adding `<wbr>` ?

Comment: @marvinIsSacul already tried and does not works, the Table plugin does not allowes HTML tags

Comment: I think the problem lies with the plugin then. you should try communicating with the plugin developers. Do they have any communication portal/medium?

Comment: can you add your full table code?

Comment: @Ashish i just added the code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0bkgLqx5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the table plugin assigns id to the `table` tag or `thead` or valid parent tag for `th`.

As an example:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="table">

<th data-class="expand" class="wdtheader sort  column-block sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Haus: activate to sort column ascending">Haus</th>

<th class="wdtheader sort  column-anzahlzimmer sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Anzahl Zimmer: activate to sort column ascending">Anzahl Zimmer</th>

<th class="wdtheader sort  column-nettowohnflache sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Netto-wohnfläche: activate to sort column ascending">Netto-wohnfläche

</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var th = document.querySelectorAll('#table th');

th.forEach(function(t) {

  var text = t.textContent;

  var output = text.replace(/[ |-]/g, '<br>');

  console.log(output); // check your browser console for output.

  t.innerHTML = output;

});
```

I am using JavaScript to replace the space " " and hyphens '-' of `th` tags content.

The replace pattern "`[ |-]`" will find any spaces or dashes and replace it with `br` tag.

You can play around with other conditions except `|` "`OR`".

**UPDATED ANSWER**

According to OP's code from fiddle.

```js
var th = document.querySelectorAll('#table_1 thead th');

th.forEach(function(t) {
  
  var text = t.textContent;
  
  var output = text.replace(/[ |-]/g, '<br>');

  t.innerHTML = output;

});
```

```html
<div id="table_1_wrapper" class="wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper">
    <div class="dt-buttons"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="wdtscroll">
        <table id="table_1" class="scroll responsive display nowrap data-t data-t wpDataTable dataTable" style="" data-described-by="table_1_desc" data-wpdatatable_id="4" role="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th data-class="expand" class="wdtheader sort  column-block sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Haus: activate to sort column ascending">Haus</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-wohnung sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Wohnung: activate to sort column ascending">Wohnung</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-anzahlzimmer sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Anzahl Zimmer: activate to sort column ascending">Anzahl Zimmer</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-etage sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Etage: activate to sort column ascending">Etage</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-nettowohnflache sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Netto-wohnfläche: activate to sort column ascending">Netto-wohnfläche</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-sitzplatz sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Aussenfläche: activate to sort column ascending">Aussenfläche</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-verkaufspreischf sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Verkaufspreis CHF: activate to sort column ascending">Verkaufspreis CHF</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-pdf sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="PDF: activate to sort column ascending">PDF</th>
                    <th class="wdtheader sort  column-anfrage sorting" style="" tabindex="0" aria-controls="table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Anfrage: activate to sort column ascending">Anfrage</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr role="row" class="odd ani-c-one">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C16 – 0.1</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">3½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">EG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 99,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 16,5 m<sup>2</sup> + Rasenfläche</td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">570’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C16-0.1.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C16%20%E2%80%93%200.1"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even ani-c-two">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C16 – 0.2</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">4½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">EG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 113,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 16,5 m<sup>2</sup> + Rasenfläche</td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">665’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C16-0.2.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C16%20%E2%80%93%200.2"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd ani-c-three">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C16 – 1.1</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">4½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">OG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 113,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 15,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">630’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C16-1.1.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C16%20%E2%80%93%201.1"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even ani-c-four">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C16 – 1.2</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">4½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">OG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 113,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 15,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">650’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C16-1.2.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.comh?subject=C16%20%E2%80%93%201.2"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd ani-c-five">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C16 – 2.1</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">3½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">Attika</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 88,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 35,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">620’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C16-2.1.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C16%20%E2%80%93%202.1"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even ani-c-six">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C18 – 0.1</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">3½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">EG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 99,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 16,5 m<sup>2</sup> + Rasenfläche</td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">590’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C18-0.1.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C18%20%E2%80%93%200.1"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd ani-c-seven">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C18 – 0.2</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">4½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">EG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 114,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 16,5 m<sup>2</sup> + Rasenfläche</td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">645’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C18-0.2.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C18%20%E2%80%93%200.2"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even ani-c-eight">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C18 – 1.1</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">4½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">OG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 112,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 15,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">650’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C18-1.1.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.comh?subject=C18%20%E2%80%93%201.1"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd ani-c-nine">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C18 – 1.2</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">4½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">OG</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 113,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 16,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">630’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C18-1.2.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C18%20%E2%80%93%201.2"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even ani-c-ten">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C18 – 2.1</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">3½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">Attika</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 88,5 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 35,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">620’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C18-2.1.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C18%20%E2%80%93%202.1"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd ani-c-eleven">
                    <td class="  column-block"><span class="responsiveExpander"></span>C</td>
                    <td class="  column-wohnung">C18 – 2.2</td>
                    <td class="  column-anzahlzimmer">4½</td>
                    <td class="  column-etage">Attika</td>
                    <td class="  column-nettowohnflache">ca. 132,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-sitzplatz">ca. 71,0 m<sup>2</sup>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-verkaufspreischf">845’000</td>
                    <td class="  column-pdf">
                        <a href="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/C18-2.2.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pdf.png" width="auto" height="20"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="  column-anfrage">
                        <a href="mailto:kirchmatt@gribi.com?subject=C18%20%E2%80%93%202.2"><img src="https://kirchmatt-breitenbach.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Anfrage.png" width="auto" height="15"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr style="display: none">
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-block" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-wohnung" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-anzahlzimmer" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Anzahl Zimmer</td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-etage" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Etage</td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-nettowohnflache" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-sitzplatz" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-verkaufspreischf" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-pdf" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
                    <td class="wdtheader sort  column-anfrage" style="" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers" id="table_1_paginate" style="display: none;"><a class="paginate_button first disabled" aria-controls="table_1" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="table_1_first">First</a><a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="table_1" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0" id="table_1_previous">Previous</a><span><a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="table_1" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">1</a></span><a class="paginate_button next disabled" aria-controls="table_1" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0" id="table_1_next">Next</a><a class="paginate_button last disabled" aria-controls="table_1" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0" id="table_1_last">Last</a></div>
</div>
```

use `onload` method to load JavaScript after your table has been loaded. You can place the script in footer too.

```
window.onload = function() { // code goes here }
```

Thanks **sarah** for mentioning `onload` method.

Comment: I tried as you suggest without results. Is a syntax error maybe?

`<script>
var th = document.querySelectorAll('#table_1_wrapper th');

th.forEach(function(t) {

  var text = t.textContent;

  var output = text.replace(/[ |-]/g, '<br>');

  console.log(output); // check your browser console for output.

});
</script>`

Comment: Did you get any syntax error? There is no any error in code. Replace the selector from `#table_1_wrapper th` to `#table_1 thead th` . It doesn't matter anyways what was the output in console?

Comment: The console should give something like `Anzahl<br>Zimmer`.

Comment: On your fiddle, I tested with the same code and it gives output as expected.

Comment: `t.innerHTML = output;` add this in the end and refresh to see your `th` text being break. Check answer for edited code.

Comment: In the jsfiddle works properly but not on my website. And the console does not give me errors

Comment: You should run your script after the table has been loaded.

Comment: I tested this code and it works perfect. However one thing that might be missing is placing the script inside window.onload = function(){} so the table has loaded first. :)

Comment: @Sarah sorry I'm really not into javascript. Could you please provide me the code you mean?

Thanks a lot

Comment: No probs. Basically put all the javascript code from the answer above inside the window.onload function as follows: window.onload = function(){ var th = document.querySelectorAll('#table_1 thead th'); etc } I don't know if thats clear enough but if not let me know.. Or maybe @Ashish could add it to his answer. :)

Comment: @wanuzi Here's a JSFiddle of the Javascript code https://jsfiddle.net/sarahmonks/ehf5ux6t/1/

Comment: @Sarah edited, thank you for mentioning onload method.